# Correct way to get server response time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a [terminable middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#terminable-middleware) that sends a request to Google Analytics. One of the attributes I send is the server response time. Here's how I do it:

In `\App\Http\Kernel` I add the `SendAnalytics` middleware:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
    ...
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        ...
        'App\Http\Middleware\SendAnalytics',
    ];
}
```

And the `SendAnalytics` middleware looks like:

```
class SendAnalytics implements TerminableMiddleware {

    protected $startTime;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->startTime = microtime(true);
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response) {
        $responseTime = microtime(true) - $this->startTime;
        /* I send a request to Google here, using their Measurement Protocol */
        // Dying for debugging purposes
        dd($responseTime); // Always prints 0.0
    }
}
```

But this always shows `0.0`. What would be the correct way to show the server response time?

Comment: If you do `dump($this->startTime);` in the constructor what does it print out? Also, what you're computing there is app execution time (and only a partial one at that, because extra processing will take place before the middleware constructor is called and after the `terminate` method). Calculating the response time means figuring how much time a few things take from the perspective of the client: DNS lookup, sending the request, waiting for the response, etc.

Comment: @Bogdan It prints the current UNIX timestamp. Eg: `1437775971.7333` is the output that I just got.

Comment: Also, I tested the response time by placing this middleware on top of all middlewares, so that it captures maximum processes, but it's still 0.

Comment: Then do a `dump(microtime(true));` in the `terminate` method and see if there is a difference. Keep in mind that if there is little code to execute it can take a few milliseconds for it to be executed, which would result in figures like `0.052...` execution time (although I can't really see how it prints `0.0` for you since `microtime(true)` returns a float with many decimals).

Comment: Ah, I just found out that `microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START` shows some significant time difference. But how accurate would that time be? Is `LARAVEL_START` the starting time for each request?

Comment: The `LARAVEL_START` constant is defined in `bootstrap/autoload.php` which is the very first file included from `public/index.php`, so this makes it the first statement to be executed. If you place the middleware last on the list, its `terminate` method will be the last one executed before `app->terminate()` will be called, so you should get a pretty good computation of execution time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I used `microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START`. Seems to give a fairly accurate response time.

As Bogdan mentions in the comment:

> The `LARAVEL_START` constant is defined in `bootstrap/autoload.php` which
>   is the very first file included from `public/index.php`, so this makes
>   it the first statement to be executed. If you place the middleware
>   last on the list, its terminate method will be the last one executed
>   before `app->terminate()` will be called, so you should get a pretty
>   good computation of execution time.

Comment: i got 0.150, is this micro second, milli second or what?

Comment: @Nevermore 0.15 seconds, or 150 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in a single request life cycle middleware instance may be initialized more than once. The second time is right before `terminate` call. That would explain zero time result (on my machine it was not zero but pretty close to it, while the actual request time was more like 200ms). The `handle` method was obviously called only once and this is where start time must be recorded.

```
class SendAnalytics implements TerminableMiddleware {

    protected $startTime;

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $this->startTime = microtime(true);
        return $next($request);
    }
    ...
}
```