# Is there a CodeIgniter Benchmark Class equivalent for Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, benchmark.js

I would like to output nifty little information about the web app and server which uses Laravel.

CodeIgniter has a dedicated library called Benchmark (https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html), and I was wondering if there is a Laravel equivalent?

It would be cool to output the Laravel equivalent to CodeIgniter's `<?php echo $this->benchmark->memory_usage();?>` and the like.

Thanks again.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647946 ... i hope this one helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

### Laravel Debugbar

Maybe you can try [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

[image: Debugbar Example]

### Laravel Telescope

I think you may also try Laravel Telescope
which to high lights the slow running quires

[Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/telescope)

[image]